# How can I convert the X-axis of the heatmap of the KEGG over-representation test to display gene symbols instead of gene entrez ID's?

Tags: r, heatmap, ontology

I'm new to coding R (and programming in general) and have recently picked it up as a requirement for my job. My lab is using an R package called "clusterProfiler" to analyze several proteins that were found in our tissue samples. Using the following code, I have been able to successfully run a gene ontology over-representation test on a sample dataset called 'geneList', and create a heatmap of biological processes that select genes are involved in. The code for this procedure is as follows:

```
devtools::install_github(
  c("guangchuangyu/enrichplot",
    "guangchuangyu/DOSE",
    "guangchuangyu/clusterProfiler",
    "guangchuangyu/ChIPseeker"))

library(DOSE)
library(enrichplot)
library(clusterProfiler)

data(geneList)

de <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]

ego <- enrichGO(de,
                OrgDb = "org.Hs.eg.db",
                ont="BP",
                readable=TRUE)

ego2 <- simplify(ego)

heatplot(ego, foldChange=geneList)
```

This method produces a heatmap that displays biological processes along the Y-axis and a list of gene symbols along the X-axis (for example, "angiogenin" is displayed as "ANG" along the X-axis).

The issue I'm having is when I run a KEGG over-representation test for the same data, and attempt to create a heatmap of the results, the X-axis does not display gene symbols, but gene entrez ID's (which are a sequence of numbers). Here is the code for the KEGG over-representation test and the subsequent heatmap:

```
data(geneList)

gene <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]

kk <- enrichKEGG(gene         = gene,
                 organism     = 'hsa')

heatplot(kk, foldChange = geneList)
```

[Sample_KEGG_Heatplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQcAu.jpg)

**My question is this:** *How can I convert the X-axis of the heatmap of the KEGG over-representation test to display gene symbols instead of gene entrez ID's?*

Comment: If the package, which creates the plot doesnt allow this option, i doubt that it can be done. I wasnt able to load the packages, as it crashed with the first, due to *corrupt database*.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply transform ENTREZ ID to genes symbol using `setRedable` method as follows:

```
new_ego <- setReadable(ego, 'org.Hs.eg.db', 'ENTREZID', keyType ="SYMBOL")

heatplot(new_ego, foldChange = geneList)
```

Hope it will help you.